# I have some trouble in the use of the class istringstream

Tags: c++

f 120208//43254 120212//43256 120178//43251 120177//43249

this is a text file content;
I use ifstringstream as:
istringstream iss
//bind;(this iss is bound to the line up);
then:

```
char c;
int k;
iss>>c>>k; //(c='f'  k= 120208)
iss>>c;  //(c='/')
iss>>k  //(here i should use iss>>c, but i use iss>>k);
```

but after this i do any thing to iss>> ,  it returns '/';and never go on;

why? how can i solve it?

Comment: Double forward slash `//` is not a valid delimiter for stream extraction. That's why it's failing. And you're not checking whether the stream failbit is set.

Comment: 'Why?' Because as soon as a read fails the stream stops working. 'How can I solve it?` Use `iss.clear();` and the stream will start working again.